# wso2 apim axis configurations files

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-api-manager

There are four files to configure the axis layer in wso2 api manager (version 1.10): `axis2_blocking_client.xml,  axis2_client.xml,  axis2.xml,  tenant-axis2.xml`.  My question is, what is the function of each file ?

For example, the message builder and formatter default configuration is not the same between the four files.  How can I know what will happen if I change one of them, all three ?

The second question is, if I want to force builder and formatter to ExpandingMessageFormatter or BinaryRelayBuilder, depending on which one I am configuring, in which file do I need to specify it ?